# Updating a list of data in a normalised table postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have two tables. One is table A which contains an id. Table B is a normalised table that contains a foreign key to table A and some other column called value.

e.g.

```
Table B
| id | fk| value

Table A 
|pk| ... |
```

Basically I have a list (of n length) of values that I want to insert into table B that are to one foreignKey e.g list = [a, b, c, d] key = 1. The problem is table B might already have these values so I only want to insert the ones that aren't already in that table, as well as delete the ones that aren't in my list.

list = [a, b, c, d], key = 1

```
table B

| id |fk | value
| 1  | 1 | a
| 2  | 1 | b
| 3  | 1 | e
```

Is there a way that I can insert only c and d from the list into the table and delete e from the table in one statement? My current attempt is to delete every entry that matches the key and then insert them all but I don't think this is the efficient way to do this.

Comment: What is `key`?  You seem to refer to it but it is not specified in any table.

Comment: key would be the foreignKey in this case. I should have clarified that!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just truncate `b` and insert the new values?

```
truncate table b;

insert into b (fk, value)
    <your list here>;
```

Or if `key` is a column in `b` and you want to delete all keys with a given value:

```
delete from b where key = 1;

insert into b (fk, value, key)
    <your list here with "1" for the key>
```

This doesn't preserve the `id` column from `b`, but your question does not mention that as being important.

An alternative method would use CTEs:

```
with data(fk, value) as (
      <your list here>
     ),
     d as (
      delete from b
           where (b.fk, b.value) not in (select d.fk, d.value from data d)
     )
insert into b (fk, value)
     select d.fk, d.value
     from data d
     where (d.fk, d.value) not in (select b.fk, b.value from b);
```

Comment: I think your first approach would remove all rows including ones which don't match the foreign key and the second approach is similar to what I'm doing already but yeah just using CTEs. I guess I was looking for a sql command that lets you delete and insert at the same time.

Comment: Truncating `b` is probably not what the OP wants to do. OP more likely wants to `delete from b where key=1;`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' . . . That is quite possible.